# How could this man weild Stormbreaker?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

During the battle scene in *Avengers: Endgame*, Thor summons Stormbreaker when he's being beaten up by Thanos. Before it reaches Thor, Thanos simply grabs Stormbreaker mid-air with his bare hands and then attempts to drive it into Thor's heart.

How could Thanos wield Stormbreaker? Is he worthy too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mjolnir has an enchantment that Odin put on it, which requires the wielder be worthy; Stormbreaker does not.